# PYTHON - PROBLEMA COM 3 VETORES

Tags: python, for, collection

Estou penando para fazer um programa que deve ler 2 vetores de 10 posições, e a partir destes criar um terceiro com os seguinte critérios:

1 - Nas posições pares, o programa deve adicionar os valores do vetor 1.
2 - Nas posições ímpares, o programa deve adicionar os valores do vetor 3.

A parte que não estou conseguindo fazer é justamente a parte onde você especifica a posição que o valor vai entrar, segue o código:

```
vetor1 = []
vetor2 = []
vetor3 = []


for n in range(0, 10):
    valor1 = int(input('digite um valor para o vetor 1: '))
    vetor1.append(valor1)

    valor2 = int(input('digite um valor para o vetor 2: '))
    vetor2.append(valor2)

for numero in vetor1:
    posicao = 0
    while posicao != 18:
    if numero % 2 == 0:
        vetor3.insert(posicao, numero)
        posicao += 2


for numero in vetor2:
   posicao = 1
   while posicao != 19:
   if numero % 2 != 0:
       vetor3.insert(posicao, numero)
       posicao += 2
print(vetor3)
```

essa foi minha tentativa final de seguir a minha lógica de que para o programa rodar eu precisaria iterar também sobre o valor 'posição' informado no insert, quando eu utilizei o while como está acima o programa não dá erro mas não retorna absolutamente nenhum valor, o programa também não termina, ele fica rodando, rodando, rodando, sem resultado.

eu tentei também utilizar o for, da seguinte forma:

```
for numero in vetor1:
    if numero % 2 == 0
        for n in range(0, 18, 2)
            vetor3.insert(n, numero)
```

a minha ideia com isso fazer com que o programa verificasse se o numero era par, e colocasse na posição n, eu fiz com que o range fosse pulando de 2 em 2,partindo do 0, pra adicionar os valores do vetor1 nas posições: 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16 e 18, que é o que o programa pede.

No entanto, quando eu rodei esse programa, o resultado foi uma lista gigante, completamente fora do que eu esperava.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Seria isso aqui https://ideone.com/tdUTBW . Veja as [operações definidas em sequências mutáveis](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)

Answer (score -3):

---

Fiz de uma maneira um pouco de diferente, veja se é esse mesmo o resultado que você está querendo.

```
vetores = {"vetor1":[],"vetor2":[]}


vezes_que_vai_rodar=3

def input_of_user(vezes_que_vai_rodar):
    for times in range(0,vezes_que_vai_rodar):
        valor1 = int(input('digite um valor para o vetor 1: '))
        vetores['vetor1'].append(valor1)

        valor2 = int(input('digite um valor para o vetor 2: '))
        vetores['vetor2'].append(valor2)

def create_a_array_with_two_differents_arrays(vetores_of_input):
    print(vetores_of_input)
    print(f"Primeiro Array {vetores_of_input['vetor1']}\n Segundo Array {vetores_of_input['vetor2']}")
    array_ordered=list()

    for vetor1,vetor2 in zip(vetores_of_input["vetor1"], vetores_of_input["or2"]):
        print(vetor1,vetor2)
        array_ordered.append(vetor1)
        array_ordered.append(vetor2)
    return array_ordered


input_of_user(vezes_que_vai_rodar)
array_finished:list = 
create_a_array_with_two_differents_arrays(vetores)

print(f"Array terminado e ordenado {array_finished}")
```

Comment: Não publique [código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/137387) e veja [mais alguns motivos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/137387). Leia [answer] e faça o nosso [tour].